# How to set expires_in in openiddict

Tags: security, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openiddict

I want to use oauth using openiddict 2.0.1 on an asp.net core 2.2 server, with an expiry time of one day, at which point I can use a refresh the token (though I'll also check for unauthorised access issues prior to expiry). However, I can't figure out how to set the expiry time.  I always get expires_in returned as 3600.

Here's what I do in startup.cs on the server:

```
// Allow client applications to use the grant_type=password flow.
options.AllowPasswordFlow();
// and refreshing
options.AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
options.SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(14));
```

and then in my authorisation context (token handler):

```
// Create a new authentication ticket for the user's principal
var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(
    principal,
    new AuthenticationProperties()
    {
        ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
        IsPersistent = true
    },
    OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

[...]
// Sign in the user
return SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties, ticket.AuthenticationScheme);
```

The return value has expires_in set to 3600 - i.e: 1 hour.  But that doesn't seem to be what I've set. There are no claims for expires_at, which seems to be what the source code looks at to produce the 3600 (not even sure how to set that?).

How can I ensure the token expires in  1 day, not 1 hour?

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the behavior you're describing: calling `options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));` correctly results in an `"expires_in": 86400` property being returned (the `ExpiresUtc` property on `AuthenticationProperties` is not used by OpenIddict). Consider posting a repro app on GitHub and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Good to know I haven't missed anything obvious. I've got a second site to build using the same basic code, so I'll see if I can repeat it there.

Comment: You could also directly set the life time on the ticket: `ticket.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(1))`